# Does SPSession ever time out?

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

When having logged in to Spotify and having an `SPSession` initialized; does it ever time out? I.e. do I have to (attempt) re-login again when the user loads the app again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when the user loads the app again"?

Not sure what you mean by that. If your application gets backgrounded, suspended and then killed then yes, you will since the entire process gets nuked.

If your application gets backgrounded and you don't open a background task, you'll get suspended and killed anyway, so the above applies.

If you get backgrounded and you *do* open a background task, things will carry on as normal until you run out of time and get suspended and killed.